# How to create a product with multiple variant quantity

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, product-attribute

I want to create a product with multiple variant of different quantity. For example I want to create a product **server with two 4GB RAM, three 1TB HDD,** etc... All the variants quantity should be in text field. If I change quantity of the variants means, It should be updated in cart price. How can I do that in **Magento 2** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want dynamic price in product detail page you can also create a bundle product. You can Bundle them to a single product and with each quantity update user can see price update in product detail page itself.

There are plenty of other options on bundle product where you can refer [here](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-bundle.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a grouped product.  Just create non visible simple products for the items you'd like to have added to the product.

So for simple products you'd have:
- 4GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- ETC

Then create a grouped product called Server and add the simple products - on the front end it will display the product with multiple text boxes where qty can be added.

Do a search for creating grouped products if unsure.  Example: https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-grouped-product/